# Correcting the usage of singular "they" and "their"

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, singular-they

*NB This is **not** a question on how to use the said terms. This is **not** a question on what the said term mean. It might just seems like so.*

Starting with the following sentences.

> It's insulting that OP needs to explain himself for each case. Sometimes he should but not always.

Now, to make it gender neutral, I rephrased to the singular *they*.

> It's insulting that OP need to explain themself for each case. Sometimes they should but not always.

The main question is this. What is the name of this rephrasal? I.e. what is the grammatically correct (possible very formal and to most people unfamiliar) term that describes such a transition?

My best guess is "*numerus based gender neutralization*". Like it?

The second question is this. I removed the ending "*s*" from "*needs*" in order to follow the plurality of the exchanged words (i.e. I'm intentionally making the mistake to fail to realize that it's a **singular** "*they*"), although "*OP*" still is singular. What's that error called grammatically correct?

My best guess is "*bogus plurality based numerus incongruence*". I don't like it at all...

NB My dictionary says that it's called "*numerus*" but I'm not sure it's the correct term neither. By *numerus* I refer to the collective set of *singular* and *plural*.

Comment: It is *politically correct*, not *grammatically correct*.

Comment: @tchrist Give me a while so I can think of another way to express the question. I've put some time into it already so it'll be a bit hard to clarify even more but I'll try. In the meantime, I hope someone gets the core of what I'm asking for so I won't have to. (Also, it's not about singular-they per se so I rollbacked your tag addition.)   :)

Comment: *neutering*, hee hee

Comment: It would be called the same thing as the use of _you_ in the singular is called; a singular use of a plural pronoun. Happens all the time. In this case it's the [third-person singular use of plural _they/their/them_ to refer to a non-specific indefinite human referent](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf). Specifically, this is a use of the **reflexive** third-person pronoun, and that's doubly-inflected. Here the form _themself_ is unambiguously singular, with the non-specific singular use of plural third-person _them_ attached. Might as well get some use out of all that inflection.

Comment: @JohnLawler There isn't any neat, shorter term for that, is there? Darn...

Comment: @guifa: [_themself_ is a recent coining; _themselves_ is standard and acceptable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/themselves-or-themself)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 "Euery creature That ys gylty and knowyth thaym-self coulpable" (OED *themself, I. 2.*) seems a bit old to be a recent coining :-)  *Themself* was the only one, then coexisted with *themselfs* and *themselves*, fell out of favor, and now is back in.  Some style guides are starting to come around on it, and I've seen a number of academic papers that use it as well (myself included).

Comment: @tchrist Please stop correcting (or, rather, **incorrecting**) the question by adding irrelevant tags. I pointed that out before and just noticed that some tags were added, so I rollbacked to the correct version. I believe I'm in a better position to judge what my question is about, especially given that you've mentioned not really seeing what I'm asking. Luckily, there was someone else who saw what I was struggling with and answered already, to my satisfaction. I believe you simply misunderstood the question despite the disclaimer. I tried to be very clear but perhaps I wasn't enough so.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Please either remove all reference to ***singular they*** from your question, or else put the tag back. You cannot have it both ways. So long as the question is about ***singular they***, that tag needs to be there.

Comment: @tchrist The question is not about *singular they*. As I kindly pointed out, you're mistaken as to what the question asks. I suggest that you take a step back and re-regard the question from some perspective (you might want to use the actual and correct answer to guide you, if it helps). I'm not looking to start a infected discussion here so I hope that the readers can respect that **I know** what I'm asking about. (The fact that an answer's been given implies that others got that too, so it's not a matter of formulation.) The question stays as is. Thank you. Downvoting was uncalled for.

Comment: The question **is** about the *singular they*. "I rephrased to the singular they. What is the name of this rephrasal?" Tags exist to help users find questions. Someone asking about what using *singular they* is called would expect other questions to be tagged like that in order to find them: it helps them find your question in order to get their answer. The tag also helps draw your question to the attention of those who are interested in this construct, because they can mark that tag as a favourite. Please respect the views of experienced users in matters of tagging.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for your input. However, I'm afraid that you're mistaken. The *singular they* is a very special thing calling for raised eyebrows amongst many non-NSEs and and such, admittedly, deserving an own tag. My question **happens** to use the word but is actually about something else. I tried to distance it from the others by not adding said tag. Please, kindly refer to the correct answer by guifa. As for the experienced users, well... If it's tchris you refer to, he claimed himself not to even understand the question so he might consider not putting his 2 cents here.  :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach After once again reviewing the question, I decided that a tag might might illuminate the intended content. It's still not the one that tchris mistakingly added, the reason of which I clarified above. (E.g. "what is 'grammatics'?" shouldn't use the tag *grammatics*, although it contains the word.) Please let me know if there's anything else I can do to improve question (as it was intended by me, of course). Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it's not just him; it's me. Please leave [singular-they] in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1: I've not really ever heard a term used for this other than just *gender neutralization*.  Since that can be done other ways, via *he/she* or most traditionally just using *he*, I'd say *gender neutralization with singular they*.  Otherwise, I mean, we could go to the extreme and say *gender neutralization via usurpation of the indeterminate/neuter/generic plural by the singular in the third person* or something over the top like that.   **Edit:** John in the comments had a good one that could be further adapted as *third-person singular use of third person plural pronouns to refer to a non-specific indefinite human referent*

Parte 2: A mistake of this type would likely just be called a subject-verb agreement error.  If I had to go with a more formal name, I'd probably say *hypercorrection of verb number due to (influence of) singular they*.  Not sure there's any other way to crunch that down further and still make sense and maintain specificity.

Comment: Besides the fact that it sounds unnatural and forced, is the usage of the term *themself* correct? Or should I use a different term (e.g. *themselves*)? In case you wonder WTF I'm asking this, let me introduce to the Kingdom of Sweden where extreme and pain-in-the-ass'ly forced feminism is our national sport. Nevertheless, I'd like to know how off from the proper grammar it is (it's far from natural and accepted state, of course, but that's beside the point here).